# Save image content inside html file

Tags: html, css, image

Is it possible to save image inside html? I want to create html with a few images. Maybe I need to decode image content with base64 and paste it in html markup?

Comment: A bit of clarification please: How do you expect to display these images- I know of a technique but without more detail in the question I don't know whether it can help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes its possible, check this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/MH7gF/

`<img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64(...)" />`

There is also simple [converter](http://www.base64-image.de/).

Comment: I also wrote a converter that can be used locally, and it is implemented as a gulp target: https://github.com/cristim/img-to-base64-html-converter

Answer (score 3):

it seems you are looking to use CSS Data URI's. http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/ you need to encode your image to base64 and set it using one of these data URI's within the HTML or the CSS as it works with both.

`<img width="16" height="16" alt="star" src="data:image/gif;base64,..." />`

```
li { 
  background: url(data:image/gif;base64,...) no-repeat left center;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use an image without the need of having it uploaded somewhere?

You can use [Mads Kristensen's image to a base64 converster](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter) tool which will return you the base64 of the image you uploaded.

EDIT: [new link](http://www.base64-image.de/)

For e.g., my avatar:

```html
<img alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
```

For CSS is the same:

```css
background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,{tons of letter/numbers here});
```

Yes, base64 is freaking huge. Therefore don't use a lot, your .html/css files will be huge as well.

Comment: Link is broken, try http://www.base64-image.de/ instead. Also, you can probably remove most of that string and your answer would be more readable.